# How to fit a fireplace insert into my existing fireplace?

Tags: heating, fireplace

I am currently not using my wood fire place and would like to put an infrared insert in. Note, there are many options for conventional, convection based heaters but I am only interested in an infrared based one. Unfortunately there does not seem to be as many options. I’d like to get this one:

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B076J9M6RW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076J9M6RW)

But the dimensions are not completely clear to me. In any case, it won’t fit into the hole perfectly.

Here is how my current fireplace looks like:

[image]

I am surprised that this insert is not somehow adjustable.

What is the the best way to make it fit? Are there adjustable frames or similar that I can put around?

Answer (score 0):

Anything you get will require custom fitting of trim.

Be aware that, depending on the model, there may be a requirement to vent for air circulation.  I have installed a number of these type of "inserts" and all of them required me to cut and make trim for a proper, safe and aesthetically pleasing install.

Also note that ANY modification to the firebox will render the fireplace useless for making any real fire.

Comment: Yes, no firebox modifications planned (I want to use it for wood in the future). It’s infrared and I haven’t found specific clearance requirements. Are there trim kits available? Or how do I best make this work? My main concern is aesthetics: I think it will look terrible if there are visible gaps around the insert

Comment: There are no trim kits that I know of. ( too many variables in fireplace designs)  There may be a Fireplace store around you that has some generic kits.  Otherwise you need to be prepared to do some trim work yourself or hire a handyman or carpenter to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You're replacing the **fire** with an electric fire, rather than wood.

The replacement fire does not need to exactly fit the front hole of the fireplace; the wood fire does not.

Consider it as being the equivalent of the logs sitting on the andirons. It merely needs to be sized to fit **in** the firebox (and you need to make sure your damper is well and throughly closed, and preferably also cap the TOP of the flue to prevent rain, birds, wasps and the like coming in, and warm air flowing out. Also helps preserve the chimney for potential future use if you are not removing it. Unless you happen to have a top of the flue damper, in which case keeping it closed should suffice.)

Comment: The damper is closed and insulation stuffed in (by previous owners). No flue installed (which is why making it wood fire ready is too expensive right now). Yes understand it can fit in the hole but my concern is aesthetics. It should be flush with the openings without gaps, otherwise it doesn’t look nice , right?